# Como excluir e depois criar todos os nomes de variáveis em um data.frame no R?

Tags: r, data.frame

Digamos que tenho um `data.frame` 6x5, exemplo:

```
print(Dados)

Linha  A   B   C   D   E
L1     4   3   2   2   4
L2     1   11  1   1   1
L3     0   1   2   3   4
L4     2   0   0   8   0
```

Mas quero excluir a "cabeça" do `data.frame`, ou seja, excluir os nomes de todas as variáveis, exemplo:

```
print(Dados_Sem_Cabeça)

    L1     4   3   2   2   4
    L2     1   11  1   1   1
    L3     0   1   2   3   4
    L4     2   0   0   8   0
```

E depois gostaria de criar uma "cabeça nova" com nomes de variáveis diferentes, exemplo:

```
print(Dados_Cabeça_Nova)

    C1   C2   C3   C4   C5  C6
    L1   4    3    2    2   4
    L2   1    11   1    1   1
    L3   0    1    2    3   4
    L4   2    0    0    8   0
```

**OBS: Não posso selecionar os nomes das variáveis pois quando o `data.frame` sofrer atualizações os nomes das variáveis irão se alterar, exemplo:**

```
print(Dados_Atualizados)

    Linha  B   C   D   E   F
    L1     4   3   2   2   4
    L2     1   11  1   1   1
    L3     0   1   2   3   4
    L4     2   0   0   8   0
```

Como posso excluir e depois criar todos os nomes de variáveis em um `data.frame`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na verdade a solução é bem simples: você não precisa excluir os nomes. Toda vez que atualizar o `data.frame` basta atualizar também quais são as colunas.

---

**EXEMPLO**

Vou criar um data.frame de exemplo a partir de uma matriz

```
dados = as.data.frame(matrix(sample(x=1:10, size = 20, replace = T), nrow=4))
```

o que pode resultar em

```
   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1  5  6  1  2  6
2  9  6  9  4 10
3  1  9  1  6  5
4 10  6  9  8  6
```

Aqui você pode atualizar os nomes simplesmente com o `colnames()`

```
colnames(dados) <- c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E')
```

e pronto, seu data.frame é agora

```
   A B C D  E
1  5 6 1 2  6
2  9 6 9 4 10
3  1 9 1 6  5
4 10 6 9 8  6
```

---

**OBSERVAÇÃO**

É um instinto meu com base na pergunta que você fez: eu acredito que pelo fato de você estar necessitando reescrever esse `data.frame` *provavelmente*
 você está abordando seu problema de alguma forma não otimizada.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Flavio Barros. Eu cheguei a mesma conclusão da sua resposta tbm.

Comment: Inclusive eu ia responder minha própria pergunta com uma resposta próxima a sua, mas vc chegou primeiro. Ótima solução!

Answer (score 2):

Você terá que passar `NULL` para o `names` do seu `data.frame`

"Excluindo":

```
names(iris)
[1] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"  "Species"     
names(iris) <- NULL
names(iris)
NULL
head(iris, 2)

1 5.1 3.5 1.4 0.2 setosa
2 4.9 3.0 1.4 0.2 setosa
```

Renomeando:

```
names(iris) <- paste0("Nome", 1:5)
names(iris)
[1] "Nome1" "Nome2" "Nome3" "Nome4" "Nome5"
head(iris,2)
  Nome1 Nome2 Nome3 Nome4  Nome5
1   5.1   3.5   1.4   0.2 setosa
2   4.9   3.0   1.4   0.2 setosa
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @Guilherme Parreira. Mas no meu caso não posso usar os nomes das variáveis porque a cada atualização do data.frame elas vão se alterando. Eu editei a pergunta acrescentando esse pequeno detalhe.

Comment: pq vc precisa excluir os nomes de fato?

Comment: Pq eu não posso selecionar por exemplo a variável "A",  pq na próxima atualização a variável se altera. Exemplo: `Variáveis_Hoje = A, B, C, D, E` e depois altera para `Variáveis_Amanhã: B,C,D,E,F`.  Se eu selecionar por nome "A" na próxima a atualização meu script vai dar erro, pq a variável "A" não vai mais existir.

Comment: A ideia de excluir a "cabeça" do data.frame é justamente fazer que meu script não dependa dos nomes das variáveis que sempre se alteram.

Comment: hum, entendi, então é utilizar o `NULL` mesmo. pois aí você não consegue chamar o nome da coluna diretamente.

Comment: Como posso utilizar o `NULL`? E como acrescentar a linha com outros nomes de variáveis? Você pode editar sua resposta esclarecendo por favor?

Comment: mas eu editei a minha resposta com o `NULL`

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92335/discussion-between-izak-mandrak-and-guilherme-parreira).